# Base R instead of dplyr: group and summarise the data?

Tags: r

The dataset is available on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results/

I want to know if we can use Base R to create an object which contains, for each combination of Sex and Season, the number of different sports in the data set?

I already used dplyr package for that and it worked:

```
data %>% 
group_by(Sex, Season) %>% 
summarise(num_sports_played = length(unique(Sport)))
```

But I would like to know if it is possible to do it with base R as well. The outcome should be a table with 4 rows and three columns(Gender, season, number of sports played).
Note: number of sports played means the total number of unique sports played, for instance: 
gender:male/ season:summer/ sport: number of unique sports that were played by male in the summer game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `aggregate`. This is the most straightforward `base` method, I think. You can use other functions as well, but this one is the easiest to follow.

```
aggregate(Sport ~ Sex + Season, data = data, 
          FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) )
  Sex Season Sport
1   F Summer    40
2   M Summer    49
3   F Winter    14
4   M Winter    17
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Base R is capable of doing these things:

```
answer <- aggregate(formula = Sport ~ Sex + Season,
                    data = data,
                    FUN = length)
```

However, when working with grouped operations, I recommend `data.table` over all other libraries (even `dplyr`). The `data.table` way of doing this is:

```
data[, nrow(), by = list(Sex, Season)]
```

I find `data.table` is more concise than `pandas`, `data.frame` and `dplyr`.